What are the failure modes for a tachometer in a light single?
During training you tend to get instructed on the various failure modes of instrumentation, such as a blocked static port and its effect on the VSI and altimeter.
This past weekend I had an instrument failure, for which I couldn't really fathom what the cause would be, short of just the dial itself (which may well be the answer!).
Cruising at  3,200ft and roughly 100 Knots the Tachometer just dropped to zero. No engine problems whatsoever, and no incident really, and landed as usual.

Is this likely to be just the failure of the instrument itself, or is there some other failure mode that might cause this whilst the engine runs as normal?

Tachs used in light airplanes have a little DC generator driven by a flex shaft from the engine accessory case. The DC generator is connected to a little volt meter measuring the generator's output, but instead of registering volts, the scale is marked in RPM. The internal drive also connects to an internal multi-stage worm drive reduction gearbox that drives a mechanical drum counter that is geared to display hours to two decimal places. It is geared to run in real time (more or less) when the engine is in its cruise RPM range.
Older car speedometers from the 60s were similar; a speed pointer driven electrically and a mechanical drum rotation counter graduated in miles.
When the dial drops to zero, either the electrical parts inside have died or the flex shaft from the engine has broken.
If the hours counter still counts as you carry on flying, you know it's the internal generator/volt meter has failed. If the counter also stops working, you know its likely that the mechanical drive shaft has sheared.

The counter stopped too, so I guess that indicates the mechanical drive shaft.

I don't know about planes, but AFIR1960s cars were generally strictly mechanical- the speedometer cable went right to the back of the speedo and rotated a magnet inside a metal cup, and also through gears to the odometer.

@Jamiec Probably. The shaft is a sort of small weed eater cable of wire windings in two directions around a core, in a flexible tube. They can fatigue where the wires are crimped into a ferrule at each end. The CRJ200 jet uses flexshafts to drive the flap system (as did the Embraer 145) and that is a failure mode they suffer from from time to time.

Update: You were pretty much spot on. "Morse cable had slipped out the drive" according to maintenance.

I believe your Tacho is of the mechanical type. It is driven by a cable with a static shaft and a rotating core. On one end the cable is attached to the engine's driveshaft, usually through some adapter, and the other end of the cable is attached to the instrument.
The instrument converts the rotation to an RPM indication. This can be done by purely mechanical means (centrifugal force & spring to drive the needle),
or converting the rotation to a voltage and measuring the voltage with an analog voltmeter showing an RPM scale (I guess this is what yours does).
Possible failure points:

the adapter itself doesn't pick up the rotation of the engine (unlikely)
bad mechanical connection of the tacho cable to adapter
a break of the tacho cable core
bad mechanical connection of the tacho cable to the instrument
broken instrument

I suspect the cable is the culprit (2., 3. or 4.) .
I had a similar problem on a 1980's car once, the cause was a cable break near the instrument.
Disclaimer: all I know about tachometers is from fixing a tacho on an old car and fixing an analog speedometer on an old bicycle. I don't have any experience with aircraft tachometers.
